# XML selection of parent based on child and/or grandchild with specific attributes

Tags: xml, search, xpath, vb6

I'm searching for an XPath string (for VBA Excel) that can look for all nodes on a specific level and that are only returned in case they have a specific (grand) child node. Regardless how 'deep' this is nested. Relationale: I don't know how deep a specific child is nested therefore I can't make a fixed path.

In case of the example below. I'm searching for all nodes that are directly under the root '' and which have any child that contain the name 'Test' but this child may not contain function '10'. However function '10' can be available on higher levels

XML STRING:

```
<Program>
   <AA name="1" function="01"/>
   <BB name="2" function="10">
      <CC name="Test" function="01"/>
   </BB>
   <DD name="Test" function="05"/>
   <EE name="3" function="01">
      <FF name="4" function="05">
         <GG name="Test" function="10"/>
      </FF>
   </EE>
</Program>
```

REQUIRED SELECTION:

```
Item(0) = <BB name="2" function="10">
Item(1) = <DD name="Test" function="05">
```

The following XPath expression gives the nodes under `Program` which contain the name 'Test'

```
xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Program/*[.//@name='Test']")
```

**How can I filter the child based on 'function'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close! Shouldn't have given up so easily!

```
//*[@name='Test' and @function !='10']
```

Or directly from `<Program>`: `/Program//*[@name='Test' and @function !='10']`

**Update:**

```
/Program/*[@name='Test' and @function !='10' or .//*[@name='Test' and @function!='10']]
```

Comment: Hello JWiley, this is not quite the answer I need. This function will return <CC> and <DD>, But I need <BB> and <DD> so the nodes directly under the root (This question is only for the principle, the real function is more complex). The function I already have returns <BB>, <DD> and <EE> but this last one I need to be filtered out

Comment: Thanks to the trigger of JWiley I found the complete code. I was missing *[...] in my code. So the complete formula looks like this.

    xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Program/*[.//*[@name='Test' and @function!='10']]")

Thanks for the trigger

Comment: @LudoHouben You are welcome, but you know the "complete formula" you have there won't get you the `<DD>` node right?

Comment: Within my complete code I use xmlDoc.selectNodes("//*[.//*[@name='Test' and @function!='10']]") and it looks that it is working.